# How to make seaborn barplot with sum of values in y-axis

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I want to make a seaborn barplot that takes year column as x-axes and sum of AveragePrice in each year as y-axes. So far i thought of groupby year but it does not seemed to be working. What should i do?

```
plt.figure()
ax = sns.barplot(avo_sales.year, avo_sales.groupby(['year'])['AveragePrice'].sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're grouping by year you need to also ensure you just have unique years for the y-axis:

```
ax = sns.barplot(avo_sales.year.unique(),
                 avo_sales.groupby(['year'])['AveragePrice'].sum())
```